# change firebase URL for FirebaseReference in Android get error: client is offline on api 29?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I try to change FirebaseReference URL but i get this error

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: Client is offline

When i run my code on emulator 33API it work, so i think there is a problem in my syntax.

here is my code

```
val database =
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("my url").reference
database.child("Iasi").addValueEventListener(object :
    ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        Log.w(ContentValues.TAG, "data ${snapshot.value}")
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.w(ContentValues.TAG, "data ${error.message}")
    }

})
```

i try another way too but still it is not work, i try with `.get().addOnCompleteListener` and i try with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.

Anybody who know what i should do?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `FirebaseOptions.Builder` like this:

```
    val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setDatabaseUrl(firebaseUrl)
        .build()

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(
        context,
        options,
        "secondary"
    )

    val app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary")
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app)
```